# ansible registering variable outputs undefined variable

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I'm trying to do this playbook for half a day. I'm using stat module to check sha1sum of file and if it is not equal to second file it should replace correct file.
But while registering some variables the output says that variables is undefined
What am I doing wrong ?

```
---
- hosts: all
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
    - name: get sum of file
      stat:
        path: /home/roundcube/config.php
        checksum_algorithm: sha1
        get_checksum: yes
      register: sum      
      
      stat:
        path: /home/archive/config.php
        checksum_algorithm: sha1
        get_checksum: yes
      register: sum2
      
    - name: result
      ansible.builtin.copy:
        src: /home/archive/config.php
        dest: /home/roundcube/config.php
      when: sum.stat.checksum != sum2.stat.checksum
```

Comment: The two *stat* tasks are redundant. The module [*copy*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html#ansible-builtin-copy-copy-files-to-remote-locations) compares the *checksum* of the *src* and *dest* by default. Quoting from  [*checksum*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html#parameter-checksum): ``'... If this is not provided, ansible will use the local calculated checksum of the src file.'``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the hyphen that defines the second stat as a task.

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
    - name: get sum of file
      stat:
        path: /home/roundcube/config.php
        checksum_algorithm: sha1
        get_checksum: yes
      register: sum      
      
    - stat:
        path: /home/archive/config.php
        checksum_algorithm: sha1
        get_checksum: yes
      register: sum2
      
    - name: result
      ansible.builtin.copy:
        src: /home/archive/config.php
        dest: /home/roundcube/config.php
        remote_src: yes
      when: sum.stat.checksum != sum2.stat.checksum
```

Note that you are also missing the `remote_src: yes` parameter in the copy task. Without it Ansible assumes that the file is on your local machine, not the remote host.

Comment: Please note that all those checks are totally useless since ansible will only copy the file if source (local or remote) and destination are actually different. Otherwise it will simply report 'OK'.

Comment: Thank You Gerald
You made my day, now it works proper. It was so simple.

Comment: Great, but heed the advice of Zeitounator and Vladimir. These checks ARE superfluous, Ansible will do the same checks again in the `copy` task.